# C2DM Show AlertDialog on Receive

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-c2dm

I have a working implementation of C2DM, if I handle each message I receive with a Toast.

Instead, I would like to use an Alert Dialog, which the user says OK to so as to acknowledge the message.

The code I've written for this generates an exception at the show() line. I expect the issue may be to do with the context used (?).

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
alertbox.setMessage("Received Push Notification");
alertbox.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    } });
    AlertDialog alert = alertbox.create();
    alert.show();
```

Full Class (as requested in comment):

```
public class MyC2DM 

extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public MyC2DM()
    {


    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Log.i("Recieve","2");
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Intent Receive!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"))
            {
                handleRegistration(context, intent);
            } 
            else if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) 
            {
                handleMessage(context, intent);
            }
         }

        private void handleRegistration(Context context, Intent intent)
        {

            String registration = intent.getStringExtra("registration_id"); 
            if (intent.getStringExtra("error") != null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Reg Error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Registration failed, should try again later.
            } 
            else if (intent.getStringExtra("unregistered") != null)
            {
                // unregistration done, new messages from the authorized sender will be rejected
                Toast.makeText(context, "Unreg!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 
            else if (registration != null) 
            {
               // Send the registration ID to the 3rd party site that is sending the messages.
               // This should be done in a separate thread.
               // When done, remember that all registration is done.

            //  UserId = customer.getId();
            //  Log.i("id",String.valueOf(UserId));

                String RegId = registration; 
                Log.i("reg",String.valueOf(RegId) );
            }
        }

        private void handleMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            // Message handler.
             Log.i("Recieve","MESSAGE");

             AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
             alertbox.setMessage("Received Push Notification");

             alertbox.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                } });
             AlertDialog alert = alertbox.create();
             alert.show();

             /*Toast.makeText(context, "ALERT: " + intent.getStringExtra("payload"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

        }
}
```

Comment: show more code.Where did you put these code.Its ok if your context has no problem

Comment: It is in `public class MyC2DM extends BroadcastReceiver` inside `private void handleMessage(Context context, Intent intent)`.

Comment: Have added whole class to submission.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to show Dialog from BroadcastReceiver and Service.Use Notification instead

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to show a Dialog in a BroadcastReceiver. I had the same problem. I created an Activity, that inherits it's style from android:style/Theme.Dialog. That made the Activity look like a Dialog.